# JAVA: Draw Gantt diagram

Tags: java, draw, gantt-chart

How to draw a Gantt chart in JAVA SWING application? Is there any free library that provides such capability? So, what is the best free option? Web-links might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [E-Gantt](http://egantt.wikispaces.com/) (it only took a few seconds of Google searching to find) :)

Edit: found a better one which is still under active development (the other was not updated since 2006): [SwiftGantt](http://swiftgantt.sourceforge.net/en/index.html).

Comment: I was waiting for some other opinions. Finally, I found out myself that one of the best available options is JFreeChart. It is very well documented. A lot of examples can be found in google.

Comment: Oh, JFreeChart does Gantt? I didn't realise -- that'd be a good solution too :)

Comment: Just one of small examples: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartGanttDemo1.htm